# I want to resume my game from the level where user left it last time

Tags: python

Need your help....
I am working on a simple game project in pygame.
My game has 12 levels.
And the problem I am facing with the game is that it start from level one whenever I quit game.
I want it to start from the same level on which I quit last time.
For example if I was on level 3 and quit the game. Then on clicking play button I want to start from level 3 again.
So please help me how to resolve this issue. I am a beginner and working in pygame for first time

Comment: Well, you probably have some code to load up a given level since you have some sort of level progression. You probably also know how to read and write text files. Put these two together, and you can save the user's last level number in a file when they start a level, and read that file when they open up your game again.

Comment: You could use a save game. Like a simple text file where the current level is stored and upon loading the game you look whether such a file exist and if it does change the current level variable based on it's content.

Comment: @AKX can you give me some reference material. Which can help me in achieving that

Comment: @haxor789 can you give me some reference material. Which can help me in achieving that

Comment: @HaiderShah The general idea is that you save information outside of your source code. That doesn't have to be complicated it technically just needs to be a file with a number. And you can use the standard file input/output:  https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-files or you could use pickle https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#module-pickle or you could use JSON (javascript object notation) as mentioned in the answer. But conceptually you just write a word or number to a file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is off-topic as it is too broad and not specific enough. The suggestions to use a file, you should be able to find documentation supplied with your Python interpreter, or online. Search for `python docs files` and you'll get https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html. Then try some things and work out how you can use it as a solution. If you get stuck you'll have a far more specific question to ask. See about how to create a [mcve]. Write a little script just to learn the Python feature you need.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you pass a new level, you must save the level.

then when the game restarts you should read the level

example

dont forget you must edit code as you want

```
import json

def readLevel():
    with open('level.json') as f:
         jsonFile= json.load(f)
         return json["level"]
def saveLevel(level):
    jsonFile={
        "level":level
    }
    with open("level.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(level, f)



def startGame():
    #your code here
    last_level=readLevel()
def nextLevel(level):
    # your code here
    saveLevel(level);
```